# Not able to scroll and double click on an element

Tags: javascript, protractor

This is my step definition:

```js
async function(string) {
//var wd = browser.driver;
 var elm = element.all(by.xpath("//label[.='Phone']/ancestor::span/following-sibling::*/input[@value='98098089']"));
 browser.executeScript(elm.getWebElement());
```

This is the error I am facing:
Then user scrolls into view on the phone value

# E2E\Tests\StepDefinitions\PanelSteps.js:189
Error: function uses multiple asynchronous interfaces: callback and promise to use the callback interface: do not return a promise to use the promise interface: remove the last argument to the function

Kindly help me in debugging this

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to handle asynchronous behavior in javascript: callback functions, promises using .then() and promises using `async/await`.

Js is recognizing your parameter `string` as a callback function but you have already declared the function as `async` and these are conflicting. I'm guessing this is because your `string` parameter is not used in your function. I would try removing it because your function is waiting for the callback to be triggered.

---

**Update:**
Adding example

```
async function sampleFunction() {
    await browser.driver.sleep(5000); 
    var elm = element(by.id("WORKPHONE")); 
    await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", elm.getWebElement()); 
    await elm.click()
}
```

Comment: Hi Dublin, Thanks for the response. I have modified the code to :   
 await browser.driver.sleep(5000);
      var elm = element(by.id("WORKPHONE"));
     await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",elm.getWebElement());
     elm.click();

It is not throwing any error now... However it is not scrolling and clicking on the desired object as well.

Comment: @MadhusmitaPadhy You need to use the `scrollIntoView()` function in your execute script and your element click after that needs to be awaited. I have added an example

Comment: I think even your `elm.getWebElement()` may need to be awaited so let me know if the above answer does not work correctly